# MAP & TEXTJOIN в таблице гугл

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Друзья, всем здравствовать!
Объединяю данные по строке с помощью `TEXTJOIN` для компактной передачи в другую таблицу, где они будут развернуты с помощью `SPLIT`. Для каждой строки записана формула:

```
=TEXTJOIN("~";0;A2:L2)
```

Т.к. количество строк постоянно изменяется, пробую использовать `MAP`:

```
=MAP(A2:L;LAMBDA(asd;TEXTJOIN("~";0;asd)))
```

но получаю входной несджойненный массив, как если бы было `=ArrayFormula(A2:L)`.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чём изъян моей конструкции и как можно одной формулой джойнить все строки на листе?

[Пример тут](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s6-np1n6ySk1P-V_7LqrxxfZfYUQn1wMtNR5-2ZZySw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения ниже.
Сначала с помощью `indirect()` формируем диапазон (левый столбец), с которого начнем склеивать. `ROWS( FILTER( A2:A ; NOT( ISBLANK( A2:A ) ) ) )+1)` находит последнюю непустую строку. В итоге формируется адрес "A2:A24". Далее ячейки этого диапазона передаются как аргумент в лямбду. В лямбде каждая ячейка расширяется до горизонтального диапазона шириной 12 ячеек с помощью `OFFSET(x;0;0;1;12)` и подается в `TEXTJOIN()` на склейку.

```
=MAP(indirect("A2:A" & ROWS( FILTER( A2:A ; NOT( ISBLANK( A2:A ) ) ) )+1);LAMBDA(x;TEXTJOIN("~";False;OFFSET(x;0;0;1;12))))
```

Реализовал на копии листа `Лист1 (копия)` в вашей книге. Сама формула в ячейке `O2`.

Comment: Отличное решение, благодарю! Именно благодаря Вашей подсказке вышел на вариант с BYROW: =BYROW(FILTER(A2:L;A2:A<>"");LAMBDA(x;TEXTJOIN("~";ЛОЖЬ;x)))

Answer (score 1):

Алексея благодарю, с его помощью найдено это решение:

`=BYROW(FILTER(A2:L;A2:A<>"");LAMBDA(x;TEXTJOIN("~";ЛОЖЬ;x)))`

Comment: Да, это решение более прямое